# Duplicated content id uploading files with large filename

Tags: plone

I am trying to upload multiples files with `collective.quickupload`.

**These are examples of filename:**

```
'habana vedado casa edificio atlantic apartamento 11A (10).jpg'
'habana vedado casa edificio atlantic apartamento 11A (11).jpg'
'habana vedado casa edificio atlantic apartamento 11A (12).jpg'
```

This plugin generate the same id for each file.

**It is using:**

```
normalizer = component.getUtility(IIDNormalizer)
newid = '.'.join ((normalizer.normalize(filename), fileextension))
```

But with this code it generates the same id for each file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but your examples are not clear. What input is used, what output is generated for `newid` and how does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: I can confirm that the same Titles are generated, not Id's! If you ment that, please adjust your question.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment is invalid, I can't delete it, though. Anyway, a filename like 'habana vedado (01)' will result in an id like 'habana-vedado-01'. Can't reproduce your problem.